# Lista de Objetos(com alguns objetos como atributos) para DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, lista, datagridview

Como eu faço para mostra a Rua ou o CEP da lista abaixo no DataGridView.

Lista de Pessoas (*para mostrar no datagridview*)

```
List<Pessoa> Pessoas;
```

Classe Pessoa

```
using System;

public class Pessoa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Endereço

```
using System;

public class Endereco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
}
```

O minha intenção é mudar o valor que aparece. Está aparecendo a pasta mais a classe: `Model.Endereco`

Comment: Como você está fazendo o *bind* do DataGrid?

Comment: 'BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();'
'bs.DataSource = _List_NfGeradaVO;'
'dgvNotas.DataSource = null;'
'dgvNotas.DataSource = bs;'

Comment: Bom, certamente é duplicada da pergunta que eu apontei. Se você procurar lá, vai ter sua solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397927.aspx) para formatar os dados, o `DataGridView` não aceita objetos agrupados, ou lista de um objeto principal, e mesmo reescrevendo `ToString()`, que eu vejo como técnica errada, não conseguiria trazer os dois campos que são essenciais a sua consulta.

Faça uma expressão com [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397927.aspx) dessa forma:

```
GridView.DataSource = Pessoas.Select(x => new 
{
  x.id,
  x.Nome,
  Rua = x.Endereco.Rua,
  Cep = x.Endereco.Cep
})
.ToList();
```

***Links:***

- [Executando consultas com LINQ e expressões Lambda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/jj128159.aspx)
- [Introdução a consultas LINQ (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx)

Comment: Boa Tarde Virgilio Novic. Sua solução me serviu perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Boa Tarde jbueno. Obrigado pelo link da pergunta que tinha sido feita anteriormente.

Comment: por nada @LuisMedeiros ...