# Procurar um string em qualquer parte da Lista c#

Tags: c#, string, winforms, lista, where

Boa Tarde. Gostaria de saber como faço para procurar uma determina string em qualquer parte da lista. Ex.: string "123". Ela pode esta em `Pessoa.id`, `Pessoa.Nome`, `Endereco.id`, `Endereco.Rua` ou `Endereco.CEP`;

Lista de Pessoas

```
List<Pessoa> Pessoas;
```

Classe Pessoa

```
using System;

public class Pessoa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Classe Endereço

```
using System;

public class Endereco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
}
```

Agradeço a todos dês de já.

Comment: você deseja filtrar, pode utilizar `Where` do `Linq`, alias da onde vem essas informações é um ORM ou carrega manualmente?

Comment: vem de uma função que retorna um List<Pessoa> que por sua vez puxa de um DB Xml...

Comment: então.. eu não sei como eu usaria o  `where` para isso... se fosse para um atributo especifico de uma das classes tudo bem.. mas eu quero para todos os atributos.. que ele busque em qualquer um.....

Comment: Luis dá para fazer de forma genérica, e até criei uma resposta com uma solução que permite realizar a busca em todos os campos de assim, incluindo campos em propriedades que sejam também objetos (como Endereco). Apesar de utilizar *reflection* e poder ter um efeito negativo na performance, dependendo dos seus dados é mais do que suficiente. Mas acho que o que você está tentando fazer seria melhor feito na camada do banco de dados, usando as funcionalidades de full text search...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158634/54880), faça um `Where` antes do `Select`:

```
GridView.DataSource = Pessoas
   .Where(c => c.Id.ToString().Contains(str) ||
            c.Nome.Contains(str) ||
            c.Endereco.id.ToString().Contains(str) ||
            c.Endereco.Rua.Contains(str) ||
            c.Endereco.Cep.Contains(str))
   .Select(x => new 
   {
     x.id,
     x.Nome,
     Rua = x.Endereco.Rua,
     Cep = x.Endereco.Cep
   })
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Adicionei uma resposta com uso de LINQ genérica. Ainda acho que será muito lenta para um volume grande de dados, mas como não sabemos o cenário completo que o Luis pretende usar pode servir para ele.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo tipo da pergunta me parece que, de fato, se trate da implementação de *Full Text Search*, onde várias, possivelmente todas as propriedades de um objeto são consideradas durante uma comparação para encontrar "registros" desejados. Isso será sempre melhor implementado na camada de dados, diretamente pelo *motor* de banco de dados. Praticamente todos, inclusive os repositórios NoSQL, implementam alguma forma de *full text search*.

Contudo, é possível resolver esta questão de forma genérica, sem precisar fazer comparação manual propriedade à propriedade. Isso envolve o uso de Reflection e pode ter um impacto negativo na performance do código à medida que aumente a quantidade de objetos sujeitos à busca.

Primeiramente, precisamos escrever uma classe com um método de extensão que nos permita "coletar" os valores das propriedades públicas de um objeto automaticamente, como string. Essa rotina precisa ser esperta o suficiente para lidar com vários tipos de dados, tais como coleções, objetos aninhados, valores nulos, etc. O código abaixo mostra como fazer isso:

```
public static class ReflectionSearchExtensions
{
    public static string CollectObjectPropertiesAsString(this object element) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (element == null || element is ValueType || element is string) {
            sb.Append(GetValue(element));
        } else {
            IEnumerable enumerableElement = element as IEnumerable;
            if (enumerableElement != null) {
                foreach (object item in enumerableElement) {
                    sb.Append(CollectObjectPropertiesAsString(item));
                }
            } else {
                var members = element.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in members) {
                    if (p != null) {
                        Type t = p.PropertyType;
                        object value = p.GetValue(element, null);
                        if (t.IsValueType || t == typeof(string)) {
                            sb.Append(value);
                        } else {
                            if (value != null) {
                                sb.Append(CollectObjectPropertiesAsString(value));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    private static string GetValue(object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return "";
        } else if (o is DateTime) {
            return ((DateTime)o).ToShortDateString();
        } else if (o is ValueType || o is string) {
            return o.ToString();
        } else if (o is IEnumerable) {
            return "...";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Agora podemos realizar a busca por **todas** as propriedades públicas do objeto da seguinte forma:

```
// para encontrar as pessoas por todos os campos usa apenas uma linha de código
var encontrados = pessoas.Where(p => p.CollectObjectPropertiesAsString().Contains(str))

// para retornar sem hierarquia de objetos
var encontrados = pessoas
    .Where(p => p.CollectObjectPropertiesAsString().Contains(str))
    .Select(p => new {
        Id = p.id,
        Nome = p.Nome,
        Rua = p.Endereco != null ? p.Endereco.Rua : null,
        Cep = p.Endereco != null ? p.Endereco.cep : null,
    });
```

**NOTA:** A rotina não trata referências cíclicas de objetos. Contudo ela trata corretamente coleções de objetos. Por exemplo, se a classe `Pessoa` fosse declarada com uma coleção de filhos a rotina procuraria também no conteúdo das propriedades de cada filho (se houver):

```
public class Pessoa {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public List<Pessoa> Filhos { get; set; }
}
```

Contudo, conforme explicado no início da resposta, essa rotina não é rápida, pois usa reflexão (*reflection*) para realizar a "coleta" dos valores das propriedades públicas como string. Existe espaço para melhorias, como por exemplo implementar um cache das propriedades por tipo de objeto, evitando que seja necessário executar `GetProperties` todas as vezes. Outra forma de melhoria, que tornaria essa rotina quase tão rápida quanto a solução "manual" mostrada abaixo, seria compilar, dinamicamente, um método para concatenar todas as propriedades públicas do objeto. Você poderia emitir o código com bom e velho `emmit` ou usar *Expression Trees* com lambdas. Sinceramente acho trabalho demais e somente seguiria esse caminho se a opção apresentada se mostrar muito lenta para os cenários reais e se não houver a possibilidade de implementar *Full Text Search* diretamente no repositório de dados (que é a solução ideal).

---

Outra forma mais simples de resolver esta questão, porém exigindo código manual, é sobrescrever o ToString() de todos as classes envolvidas de forma que todos os campos "buscáveis" sejam incluídos. Dessa forma:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1} - {2}", id, Nome, Endereco);
    }
}

public class Endereco
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string cep { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1} ({2})", Rua, cep, id);
    }
}
```

Uma vantagem desse método é que ele evita problemas com campos nulos, como quando o `Endereco` for `null`.

Para encontrar as pessoas desejadas bastará fazer:

```
var encontrados = Pessoas.Where(p => p.ToString().Contains(str));
```

Ou, seguindo a ideia da resposta do Virgilio Novic:

```
var encontrados = Pessoas
    .Where(p => p.ToString().Contains(str))
    .Select(p => new {
        Id = p.id,
        Nome = p.Nome,
        Rua = p.Endereco != null ? p.Endereco.Rua : null,
        Cep = p.Endereco != null ? p.Endereco.cep : null,
    });
```